# How can I check if a month has 31 days or not

Tags: python

Below is code to work out if a given date is invalid or not. How do I say:

(`if 31 == days AND the month isn't 1,3,5,7,8,10 or 12) OR (there are 32 <= days`), date invalid.

I tried just using what I said above but I don't think I understand how python OR statements work... the code looks long but is *hopefully* simple enough so that it doesn't take to much time to read through.

```
startMonthQuery = int(input(" What month are you starting in?\n>"))
startDayQuery = int(input(" What day are you starting on?\n>"))

if startMonthQuery <= 0:
  print("That is not a valid month, please don't put zero or a negative number.")
elif startMonthQuery >= 13:
  print("That is not a valid month, please do not put a thirteen or higher.")

if startDayQuery <= 0:
  print("That is not a valid day, please do not put a zero or negatuve number.")
elif (startDayQuery >= 32)
  print("That is not a valid day, it either doesn't have 31 days or you have entered a number far too high.")
```

Sorry if this took to long to read^

Comment: Do you mean something like this `if startDayQuery == 31 and startMonthQuery not in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] or startDayQuery <= 32:`? Note that the statement itself is rather meaningless, as the conditions of the first part are superseded by the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some Python code to validate dates in an online [tutorial](https://followtutorials.com/2019/03/python-program-to-check-if-a-date-is-valid-or-not.html) (if that's really your goal). Below is a copy of the code.

(Note that it does *not* use the `calendar` module, BTW.)

```
year = int(input("Enter year: "))
month = int(input("Enter month: "))
day = int(input("Enter day: "))

# Get Max value for a day in given month
if month == 1 or month == 3 or month == 5 or month == 7 or month == 8 or month == 10 or month == 12:
    max_day_value = 31
elif month == 4 or month == 6 or month == 9 or month == 11:
    max_day_value = 30
elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
    max_day_value = 29
else:
    max_day_value = 28

if month < 1 or month > 12:
    print("Date is invalid.")
elif day < 1 or day > max_day_value:
    print("Date is invalid.")
else:
    print("Valid Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
month=datetime.datetime.now()
if month.month in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12):
  print("it has 31 days in this month")
elif month.month in(4,6,9,11):
  print("it has 30 days ")
else:
  print("it has 28 or 29 days")
```

Comment: you might want to explain how your answer works or what did you change in the source code to make it more clear to the community :) . And also maybe add an output result also .